# How to write unit test for code taking user input in python3

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, user-input

I have made a calculator in python3.

```
class simple_oper:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    @staticmethod
    def add(num1, num2):
        return num1 + num2
    @staticmethod
    def subtract(num1, num2):
        return num1 - num2
    @staticmethod
    def mul(num1, num2):
        return num1 * num2
    @staticmethod
    def div(num1, num2):
        return num1 / num2
def get_int(input_message, tm):
    num = input(input_message)
    try:
        return int(num)
    except:
        return get_int(tm, tm)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    num1 = get_int("Please enter the first number : ", "Please enter the correct number : ")
    l = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]
    #c = simple_oper
    while True:
        oper = str(input("Please enter the operand to do : "))
        if oper == "=":
            print("You typed = printing result")
            break
        elif oper not in l:
            print("Ypu typed incorrect operand. aborting and printing result")
            break
        num2 = get_int("please enter the number : ", "please enter the correct number")
        if oper == "+":
            num1 = simple_oper.add(num1, num2)
        if oper == "-":
            num1 = simple_oper.subtract(num1, num2)
        if oper == "*":
            num1 = simple_oper.mul(num1, num2)
        if oper == "/":
            num1 = simple_oper.div(num1, num2)
    print(num1)
```

Now I want to write unit test for it. But the problem here is that my code takes many user inputs. So how do I write such a unit test that it can give inputs to my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when you write classes in any language, you would generally leave the user input outside of the class, in a separate file. For unit testing, you wouldn't test input, you'd test the logic of the class itself. Your unit test would look something like this:

```
import unittest
from simple_oper import simple_oper

class Test_Simple_oper(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        self.assertEqual(simple_oper.add(3,3), 9)
        self.assertEqual(simple_oper.add(-10,4), 6)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

You get it, something like that. You'd add more methods until you test all your methods in simple_oper. The unit test tests the program's logic, where you test many possibilities that the user can put, not user input.